# Rails - The url redirect me on the wrong user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where a **user** can suggest some **trips**.

As the current user I want to visit his profile.
I am kinda stuck because I arrive on my own profile...
The nickname is well displayed,but the url redirect on the current user.

```
<div class="container">
      <h1><%= @trip.name %></h1>
        <% if current_user.id == @trip.user.id %>
          <%= link_to  "Edit", edit_meal_path(@trip), class: "btn btn-warning"  %>
        <% end %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
       <!--probleme is right below  -->
      <h3>Suggested by <%= link_to @trip.user.nickname, user_path(@trip.user)%></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to redirect on the guy who suggested the trip's profile??

my show action in my controller, I have a **before_action** set to find the trip_params

```
  def show
    @order = Order.new
    @review = Review.new
    @user = @trip.user
  end
```

### EDIT:

I tried to change the `id` in the `localhost:3000/users/2` but whatever the id number I add I stay on my current_user's profile

Comment: Then there must be something wrong in the controller

Comment: I added my show action @Iceman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your users controller
Make sure to have `@user = User.find(params[:id])`
According to what you explained you may have `@user = current_user`